How to use apt to install MySQL 8.0.37 on Ubuntu 22.04
I've installed MySQL 8 on Ubuntu using APT but a scan detected that my MySQL 8.0.36 has security risks, but the latest version available for Ubuntu 22.04 is still MySQL 8.0.36.
Is it a problem? Do I need to manually download and update MySQL to 8.0.37?
See the security alert:
https://www.oracle.com/security-alerts/cpuapr2024.html#AppendixMSQL

In the meanwhile I've downloaded MySQL 8.0.37 from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and selected this menu:

Install Using APT: (mysql-apt-config_0.8.30-1_all.deb)`

But it seems I've installed 8.0.37-1ubuntu20.04 (note the 20.04). How can I use apt to install 8.0.37-1ubuntu22.04 on Ubuntu 22.04, or do I need to use another method?

This question was posted the 27 of May 2024. Ubuntu published a patch the 11 June 2024: https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-6823-1
So after 11 June 2024 the answer is https://askubuntu.com/a/1532323/263638
No need to replace the official package with something installed manually.

This is really two questions. The question should be "I have a security issue, what should I do?" and the answer is "apt update && apt upgrade" :) No need to replace native package that has support from Ubuntu security team.

Hoping to be useful I've tried to edit a bit the question to add more context. Thanks since this question is still very useful to people who just want to understand how to install MySQL 8 on Ubuntu 24.04 jammy. But fortunately that is simple, and also updating it is simple.

You can use the MySQL APT Repository and replace your Ubuntu native distribution of MySQL.

Backup your database

Go to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/ and download the latest package.
At the time of writing this, it's mysql-apt-config_0.8.30-1_all.deb and can be downloaded with wget like this:
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.30-1_all.deb


Install the package
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.30-1_all.deb


Install the new mysql-server package.
At the time of writing this, it installs MySQL 8.0.37:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server



Warning:
Once the native distribution of MySQL has been replaced using the MySQL APT repository, purging the old MySQL packages from the native repository using the apt-get purge, apt-get remove --purge, or dpkg -P command might impact the newly installed MySQL server in various ways. Therefore, do not purge the old MySQL packages from the native repository packages.

Yes, I installed it like this, but after installation it was "8.0.37-1ubuntu20.04" instead of "8.0.37-1ubuntu22.04", but my current Ubuntu version is 22.04

This is strange, on my machine it installed 8.0.37-1ubuntu22.04.

@cruise Can you edit your question and add the output of: apt-cache policy mysql-server and cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list and cat /etc/lsb-release.

When I run "sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.30-1_all.deb" there is only "MySQL Server & Cluster (Currently selected: mysql-5.7)
MySQL Tools & Connectors (Currently selected: Enabled)
MySQL Preview Packages (Currently selected: Enabled)
mysql-8.0 mysql-cluster-8.0
But other machines have other versions

It should be a problem with the machine. I don’t know what the problem is specifically. I ran it normally on other machines, including the latest version of MySQL 8.0.37 and multiple versions of MySQL 8.4.

The original question was about how to resolve a security issue found in a package. The solution is to run apt update && apt upgrade without manually removing native packages and without any manual installation of software from the Oracle's website. Manually installing software from websites makes it much more complicated to update them in the future.

If you are using Ubuntu jammy 22.04, and if you want to install MySQL 8, just use the official native package mysql-server-8.0, and just use the native APT package manager. So, to install latest version of MySQL 8 on Jammy, just run this in your terminal:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server-8.0

If you detect security issues, just upgrade the packages with your terminal:
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

That's all, really. This is true at least since Ubuntu 22.04 remains an LTS and receives official security fixes by Ubuntu Security Team. No need to replace the native package with something manually downloaded from the website of Oracle. Note that the official package for Ubuntu jammy now provides 8.0.39 at the time of writing, that is quite recent. Here package information for jammy:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/database/mysql-server-8.0
Note that in general, even if a specific package seems affected by a security issue, very probably Ubuntu already provided a minor patch and you just need an apt upgrade as already said. Security patches are announced here, for Jammy:
https://ubuntu.com/security/notices?release=jammy
https://ubuntu.com/security/notices?order=newest&release=jammy&details=mysql
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ
